# Derive Equation for Position of Antinode

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, string

I'm not sure what to do for this.

The equation for standing waves on a string is given by:
$$
y=2A\sin{(kx)}\cos{(\omega t)}
$$
Use this equation to derive an equation for the position of the antinodes.

Comment: Hint: the antinodes occur where $dy/dx=0$.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/76138/392

Answer (score 1):

Taking the derivative of equation $y$ (as the hint states) and solving $x$ such that it is zero will give you your answer:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(2A\sin\left(kx\right)\cos\left(\omega t\right)\right)=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Look at the equation. There are two components - one describes variation of the max amplitude with position (the $\sin (kx)$ part) and the other describes the variation with time ($\cos(\omega t)$).

The antinodes must occur where the max amplitude is as big as possible (so where $|\sin(kx)|=1$).

This will happen at multiple locations (there will be a $\mod(\pi)$ in your answer)